# windows 10 pro admin runas /savecred without security flaws

Tags: windows, security

I want to allow a non-admin user to open a program that requires admin rights, without admin entering password each time user wants to open it.

At first I thought this would be easy to achieve with "open as administrator" in .exe properties, but it is not working for this particular .exe because it also needs to access to other services (fetch data from devices on the network).
I found this solution afterwards: https://superuser.com/a/903881/1807813
Unfortunately the scheduled task solution is not working either because the program must be interactive.

- Would the only way be to use the "runas /savecred" shortcut method?

If yes however, "runas /savecred" will keep password in Credentials Manager, and can be used anywhere else on the system, either on cmd/ps or directly in an other shortcut.

- In that case is it possible to restrict the use of a stored password to a single program with Credentials Manager?

Another solution would be to restrict the rights to open cmd/ps for the user. However the user should still be able to create shortcuts on his own, so the security flaw still exists, and this solution can't be applied.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.